# Set sequential tag name multiple ec2 instances in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

My goal for this ansible playbook is to start up to 8 ec2 instances depending on what is already running. The part I'm having trouble finding information on is naming/tagging the instances in a sequential order. Is there a way to tag_Name to be ansible-test-1 through 8?

Here's what I have:

```
- name: Provision EC2 instances
      ec2:
        key_name: "{{ aws_public_key }}"
        instance_type: t2.small
        image: "{{ aws_ubuntu_ami }}"
        wait: true
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ dev_subnet_public }}"
        group_id: "{{ aws_group }}"
        assign_public_ip: yes
        instance_tags:
          Name: ansible-test
          environment: qa
        exact_count: 8
        count_tag:
          Name: ansible-test*
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        volumes:
          - device_name: /dev/sda1
            volume_size: 300
      register: ec2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
- name: Provision EC2 instances
      ec2:
        key_name: "{{ aws_public_key }}"
        instance_type: t2.small
        image: "{{ aws_ubuntu_ami }}"
        wait: true
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ dev_subnet_public }}"
        group_id: "{{ aws_group }}"
        assign_public_ip: yes
        instance_tags:
          Name: ansible-test-{{item}}
          environment: qa
        count: 1
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        volumes:
          - device_name: /dev/sda1
            volume_size: 300
      register: ec2
      with_items:
        - 1
        - 2
        .....
        - 8
```

Another way of doing it would be modifying the tag after instance creation in next task using `ec2_tag`

Answer (score 0):

Use `with_sequence`

Example:

```
- name: Provision EC2 instances
  ec2:
    key_name: "{{ aws_public_key }}"
    instance_type: t2.small
    image: "{{ aws_ubuntu_ami }}"
    wait: true
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ dev_subnet_public }}"
    group_id: "{{ aws_group }}"
    assign_public_ip: yes
    instance_tags:
      Name: ansible-test-{{item}}
      environment: qa
    with_sequence:
      count: 8
    exact_count: 8
    count_tag:
      Name: ansible-test*
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    volumes:
      - device_name: /dev/sda1
        volume_size: 300
  register: ec2
```